# How to create columnspan in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid like below. Here I am getting problem with "**Hours Last 52 Weeks**". Here I have to use this text over the grid headers like the below screen. How can I use this? Highlighted in "Yellow" is the actual text.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's a declarative way to do this, but you should be able to add a handler for `RowDataBound` in which you check for `RowIndex` of 0 and if so, update the row's `Cells` accordingly. `TableCell` has a `ColumnSpan` property, and you might also have to remove the cells you're absorbing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataList with colspans, e.g.

```
                   <asp:DataList ID="cm_DataList" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  border="0" align="center" width="100%" class="RepTable01">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="rptHeading">Phases</td>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="rptHeading">Phase 1</td>
                                    <td colspan="3" class="rptHeading">Phase 2</td>
                                    <td colspan="4" class="rptHeading">Phase 3</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="rptHeading">Meeting</td>
                                    <td class="rptSubHeading">Meeting 2</td>
                                    <td class="rptSubHeading">Meeting 3</td>
                                    <td class="rptSubHeading">Meeting 4</td>
                                    <td class="rptSubHeading">Meeting 5</td>
                                    <td class="rptSubHeading">Meeting 6</td>
                                    <td class="rptSubHeading">Meeting 7</td>
                                    <td class="rptSubHeading">Meeting 8</td>
                                    <td class="rptSubHeading">Meeting 9</td>
                                    <td class="rptSubHeading">Meeting 10</td>
                                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td class="rptHeading">Meetings Nr</td>
                                    <td class="rptCell"><%# Eval("meeting1") %></td>
                                    <td class="rptCell"><%# Eval("meeting2")%></td>
                                    <td class="rptCell"><%# Eval("meeting3") %></td>
                                    <td class="rptCell"><%# Eval("meeting4") %></td>
                                    <td class="rptCell"><%# Eval("meeting5") %></td>
                                    <td class="rptCell"><%# Eval("meeting6") %></td>
                                    <td class="rptCell"><%# Eval("meeting7")%></td>
                                    <td class="rptCell"><%# Eval("meeting8")%></td>
                                    <td class="rptCell"><%# Eval("meeting9")%></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
```